# Rhythmbox doesn't recognize mp3 files

Tags: debian, gstreamer, rhythmbox

When I try to import my music library in Rhythmbox, it doesn't recognize any of the files as music (all mp3). When I try to play one of the files directly, I get an import error in Rhythmbox that reads `Problem occurred without error being set. This is a bug in Rhythmbox or GStreamer`. I can play the files with another player like VLC or Videos.

I've already reinstalled Rhythmbox which didn't change anything, so I tried to reinstall GStreamer and I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg : Depends: gstreamer1.0-libav (= 1.14.1-1) but 1:1.10.4-dmo1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-python3-dbg-plugin-loader : Conflicts: gstreamer1.0-python3-plugin-loader but 1.14.1-1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-python3-plugin-loader : Conflicts: gstreamer1.0-python3-dbg-plugin-loader but 1.14.1-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This seems strange to me, why is `gstreamer1.0-libav 1.10.4-dmo1` going to be installed if a newer version is required?

I am running Debian testing with the unstable repository pinned at a lower priority and testing set as default.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions from https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages#223267 ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't seen this. I have no held packages, I am using aptitude and unfortunately the `-f` flag results in the same output.

Comment: What happens if you request installation of the dependency while specifying the exact version with `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav=1.14.1-1`?

Comment: Usually you need the 'ugly' plugins for copyright encumbered MP3 etc. formats. See if the plugins are installed.

Comment: @ajeh thanks, the ugly plugins are installed.  
@Hermann this I could install the correct version like this (it says downgraded so apparently `1:1.10.4-dmo1` is newer). However, when I try to reinstall gstreamer I still get the error for the two python plugins. There it doesn't give me an exact version that should be installed, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you requested to install both `gstreamer1.0-python3-dbg-plugin-loader` and `gstreamer1.0-python3-plugin-loader` at the same time. Can you remove them? I do not see how they are important for MP3 playback anyway.

Comment: Also, comments in https://askubuntu.com/questions/750418/my-rhythmbox-not-playing-mp3 are hinting that Rhythmbox/GStreamer needs write permissions on the files. Looks weird to me, but it may be that way.

Comment: Hi Hermann, thanks for your help. The two plugins were not installed, the output I gave is the result of `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0`. For some reason gstreamer wants to install both plugins, although they conflict with each other. However, it was possible to install both plugins manually, doesn't that mean they don't actually conflict? I still get the same error when I try to install gstreamer after installing the two plugins manually. I don't think it's because of permission issues, all my music is owned by my user and permission is 777.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Might not be related to the installed packages after all.

Comment: "Solved" it by reinstalling my system. I think purging VLC somehow messed up my gstreamer installation.